# Can't print in Mike42/ESCPOS via CUPS, I get "Command lpstat -a failed: lpstat: Scheduler is not running" error

Tags: php, cups, escpos

I'm trying to print in CUPS with Mike42/ESCPOS library but when I declare a new CupsPrintConnector the server gets a "Command lpstat -a failed: lpstat: Scheduler is not running" fatal error.

When I run the command in the terminal I get a "printer accepting requests" affirmative answer but I try to run

```
exec("lpstat -a",$output,$code);
```

...and nothing, I get an empty response. My guess is somehow apache user lacks some permission or something but I just don't know what else to do. I created groups and added the user, unistalled and reinstalled the printer and nothing works.

I'm using Fedora. I tried with raspbian in an Orange Pi and it works there.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was formatting Fedora and installing Ubuntu. I'm sorry if that's not a real solution.